# What are the connotations of a "foot-washing baptist"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, connotation, books

In the book, *To Kill a Mockingbird*, the foot-washing baptists seem to be painted by Miss Maudie to be evil and to have a strict adherence to the "cleanliness of the soul."

When Scout asks Miss Maudie if she is a "foot-washing baptist," Miss Maudie replies with "my shell's not that hard." To me, that means that being a foot-washing baptist has negative connotations, as Miss Maudie does not want to associate herself with such a group. Am I right in inferring that a "foot-washing baptist" is dissimilar from a baptist that practices foot-washing?

What are the connotations of "foot-washing baptists" outside the context of the book?

Comment: This isn't a question about the English language but about the practices of the Baptist Church.

Comment: And it isn't so much a question about the Baptist Church as it is opinions about particular ritual practices within the Christian communities of faith and their implications about the state of being human. If you're reading this book as a classroom assignment, you should ask your teacher what the author means by this expression. It would be a good discussion for the entire class to participate in.

Comment: [Washing of the Feet, is a religious rite observed by several Christian denominations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foot_washing). Which prompts me to closevote [Where did “Cleanliness is next to Godliness” originate?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44130/) as well as this one.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I've edited the question to try and explain my thoughts slightly better

Comment: http://www.enotes.com/homework-help/what-foot-wing-baptist-according-miss-maudie-book-77841

Comment: Ronikos It's still cultural history / Lit Crit. I assume Miss Maudie's [*"My shell's not that hard, child. I'm just a Baptist."*](http://genius.com/Harper-lee-to-kill-a-mockingbird-chapter-5-annotated) is a "tongue-in-cheek" way of saying *I'm not **that** much of a [religious nut](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=religious+nut)*. But if you wanted to take a harder line, you could read the entire extended allusion as claiming people who indulge in such "extreme" religious practices are metaphorically "hard-shelled", and care more about rituals than *people*.

Comment: "OK, Google ... Foot-washing Baptist."

Comment: The allusion is to a Baptist sect which has the practice of ceremonially washing each other's feet.  There certainly are such "Bible-thumping" sects (and they can be really unpleasant to work with at times).  Whether the term is being used literally or figuratively, though, is for you to figure out.

Comment: The ceremony of foot washing is generally considered a positive thing. If it's a negative thing in TKAMB then that's a peculiarity of American culture. Cultural questions are usually not considered on-topic here sorry.

Comment: The poster is asking about an English phrase that he or she couldn't make sense of—presumably (giving him or her the benefit of the doubt) after trying to find the answer him- or herself. The answer isn't readily available, in any case. Under the circumstances, I think this is a valid question of word/phrase meaning.

Comment: @FumbleFingers What do these two questions have in common if anything? This one about feet is about cultural references, and the one about cleanliness is about the source of the common proverb. The latter was judged to be on-topic here.

Comment: @Mitch: What they have in common is both questions are essentially about Off Topic *cultural history*, not "use of English". I can't help it if not everyone here agrees with me on this.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The second one about cleanliness is not about culture. The ELU community judged long ago that provenance of quotes is on -topic.

Comment: @Mitch: To quote from the link in the accepted answer: [CLEANLINESS IS NEXT TO GODLINESS - "This ancient proverb is said by some to have come from ancient Hebrew writings.](http://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/5/messages/1209.html) Like I say, I can't help it if not everyone here agrees with me that aphorisms that predate English should be considered Off Topic.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - "Cleanliness is next to godliness" has little to do with Baptist foot washing.  The practice relates to the biblical account of Jesus washing the apostles' feet, presumably as a show of humility.

Comment: @Hot Licks: I never suggested the two questions are *that* closely related (I said nothing about either being closed as a duplicate). I'm simply saying that the meaning of "foot-washing baptist" is a matter of Lit Crit and/or cultural history, and the origin of “Cleanliness is next to Godliness” is also just cultural history. I mean, come on! OP himself actually *says* here that he wants to know what a "foot-washing baptist" means *outside the context of the book*. So the *only* context we're supposed to be addressing is the "cultural history" connotations of an oddball religious practice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mitford Mathews, *A Dictionary of Americanisms on Historical Principles* (1951) has this entry for "foot washing Baptist":

> **foot**, *n.* ... **3.** In comb[ination]s: ... (13) **[foot] washing**, an occasion upon which Primitive Baptists wash each other's feet as a religious memorial; (14) **[foot] washing Baptist**, a member of any one of several sects of Baptists who practice foot washing;

Also of note is Mathews's entry for "Primitive Baptist":

> **Primitive Baptist,**  a Hard Shell or Old School Baptist. Also attrib. [First citation is to *Polly Peablossom* (1851)].

And for "Hard-shell Baptist":

> **Hard-Shell Baptist,** a member of the Primitive Baptist Church, or Old-School or Antimissionary Baptist. [First citation is to *Knickerbocker* magazine (1845).]

*Hard-shell* has the transferred sense of "A severe or strait-laced person," according to Mathews.

One early Google Books match for "foot-washing Baptists" is from [*Annual Session of the Baptist Congress*](https://books.google.com/books?id=6j48AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA99&dq=%22foot-washing+baptist%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiSqYuY2v_KAhVC0GMKHa1tCgsQ6AEIKjAA#v=onepage&q=%22foot-washing%20baptist%22&f=false) (1899), in an address to the congress by Rev. Emory Hunt, of Toledo, Ohio:

> In the records of the Miami Baptist Association, the first formed in the northwest territory, we find that in 1807 a query came up from the Union church on Indian Creek, "whether the washing of saints' feet be an example left on record for the professed followers of Christ to be continued in his church." The association laid it over for one year and then replied, "we consider every church independent, and if the church on Indian Creek, or any other, agree among themselves on this point it will not affect their fellowship with their sister churches." We may doubt whether a **foot-washing Baptist** church would be made comfortable in a Baptist association to-day.

It thus appears that "foot-washing Baptists" were a category of Baptists who believed in emulating the biblical ritual of washing the feet of holy persons in some of their ceremonies. Further, when Miss Maudie says in *To Kill a Mockingbird* that she doesn't have as hard a shell as that, she simply means that her religious beliefs are not so straitlaced and severe as those of Hard-Shell or Primitive Baptists (who evidently consider foot washing to be an appropriate religious ritual).

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to the people who feel that they can take the word at its face value may be wrong.

My interpretation is, with the context of the book in mind, a foot-washing Baptist is a person who takes the Bible literally with a very crude interpretation, for example, they believe that women are a sin by definition as Eve was the first to eat from the Tree of Knowledge, disobeying God.

This is why Miss Maudie says, "my shell's not that hard." A "foot-washing Baptist" may be Baptist who practises in the washing of feet, but it may also mean a Christian believer who takes the Bible literally, with parallels to a creationist.

I will not make any judgements on any sort of denomination of Christianity, I'll let every finish the interpretation with their own thoughts.

Comment: There likely is some truth to what you say, though I don't think the literal interpretation (of, ironically, biblical literalists) should be ignored.  The two kind of go hand-in-hand.